# Creating new tables on the fly with Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, schema, sequelize.js

I'm implementing nodejs app that saves data to database. Application takes post request from /add and it is supposed to take two arguments (actual data and table name). All tables are going to contain same fields and datatypes that are defined in model file.

Table name tells where data is going to be saved. Currently my app works fine when it comes to saving data to one table (named Test) but this should be extended to work with multiple tables. Tables should also be created if they don't exist.

I have created model for Sequelize:

```
// The model schema.
const modelDefinition = {
  data: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON,
    allowNull: false,
  },
};

// Define the model.
const SensorModel = db.define('Test', modelDefinition, modelOptions);
```

I have seperate controller file where data is added:

```
sensorController.addData = (req, res) => {
    db.sync().then(() => {
  const newSensor = {
    data: req.body.data,
  };
  return Sensor.create(newSensor).then(() => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: ' data added!',
    });
  });
});
```

};

from route file:

```
router.post('/add', sensorController.addData);
```

Currently this only creates table called test and adds data there. I want to extend this so that table name can be specified when adding new data but I'm a bit lost with this and don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to create new tables on the fly?  How will you know what to call the fields?  And their datatypes?  And whether or not there are any foreign keys?

Comment: The fields and datatypes are used from model file. No foreign keys etc  used. Is this possible? Any other suggestions?

Comment: As Dan Bracuk mentioned, I can't imagine why you would want to create tables and columns on the fly. That said, you can perform raw queries in Sequelize (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) so you could technically perform all the DB operations you want

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
console.log('name_table:', youModel.getTableName())
youModel.tableName='NEW_TABLE_NAME';
console.log('name_table:', youModel.getTableName())
```

It works for me.